# I get a function A and function C.The function B is in the function

Tags: javascript, function

How to call C in the function B.

```
Function A(){function B(){}} 
Function C(){}
```

I have tried direct call it in the

```
function B(){C();}
```

But nothing to be done.

Comment: That looks fine to me.  What do you mean "nothing to be done"?

Comment: `function A(){function B(){C();} B();}`?

Comment: Yes.But nothing happend.

Comment: Is that because `C` does nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `A()`, you'll have to call `B()` so you can call `C()`. Until you execute, it's all just declarations.

```
function A() {
    console.log("I'm function A");
    function B() {
        console.log("I'm function B");
        C();
    }
    B();
}
function C() {
    console.log("I'm function C");
}

A();

// or

function A() {
    console.log("I'm function A");
    (function B() {
        console.log("I'm function B");
        C();
    })();
}
function C() {
    console.log("I'm function C");
}

A();

// or

function A() {
    console.log("I'm function A");
    (function B(callback) {
        console.log("I'm function B");
        callback();
    })(C);
}
function C() {
    console.log("I'm function C");
}

A();

//or

(function A() {
    console.log("I'm function A");
    (function B(callback) {
        console.log("I'm function B");
        callback();
    })(C);
})()
function C() {
    console.log("I'm function C");
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/bkpCt/2/)

### And my personal favorite

```
(function A(callback) {
    console.log("I'm function A");
    (function B(callback) {
        console.log("I'm function B");
        callback();
    })(callback);
})(C)
function C() {
    console.log("I'm function C");
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/bkpCt/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This is valid function call of C from B

```
function A(){function B(){C();}
```

I hope in your real code you have some statements in those functions to identify whether the calls are happening as desired.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a function in javascript you just need to call:

```
 c();
```

You only use

```
 function X(){}
```

when declaring a function

Answer (score 0):

Your code could look something like this:

```
function C(){
  console.log("This is C");
}
function A(){
 console.log("this is A");
 function B(){
   console.log("this is B and can only be called within A");
   C();
 }
 B();
}
A();// shows:
  // this is A
  // this is B and can only be called within A
  // this is C
C();//shows this is C
B(); // causes error: ReferenceError: B is not defined
```

To open and see the console you can press F12 in firefox, chrome or opera. In IE I don't know exactly.